# designing many producers one consumer two way communication

Tags: c#, producer-consumer

I'm writing trading software. My system produces "sequential items" (1,2,3...) that need to be processed (in my application each item is an order for execution and id is so called internal order id).

I have many threads that can produce items (many strategies), but it is guaranteed that each item will be produced **exactly** once.

I have only one Processor(order executor) that should

- whenever new item is available submit it for execution (place order)
- in callback receive result and update it "item result" (get response from stock exchange)

Each  producer should

- submit "sequintial pack" of items for execution (for example submit "1234,1235,1236,1237")
- block until results for all items is available. when results for all items is available - process

Note that:

- items can be submitted from different thread in parallel
- i neeed minimal latency and minimum "locks"
- it's nice to have a code that easy to port to c++
- at any time I have pretty "limited" number of "live" id's. For example i can not have at the same time live id's "1 and 10000". Because whenever new id is created - it must be processed and clean-up. So I always have set of id close to each other (for example ~9900-10000). So it's likely makes sense to use cycle-array for implementation

If you can suggest something - please suggest. I'm adding my strange implementation below, but it is not necessary to read it.

---

This is my *prolem* implementation:

```
    private Dictionary<uint, AutoResetEvent> transactionsEvents = new Dictionary<uint, AutoResetEvent>();
    private Dictionary<uint, TransactionResult> transactionsResults = new Dictionary<uint, TransactionResult> ();

    public void IssueOrders(List<OrderAction> actions)
    {
        int count = actions.Count;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        uint finishUserId = (uint) apiTransactions.counter.Next(count);
        uint startUserId = finishUserId + 1 - (uint) count;

        AutoResetEvent[] events = new AutoResetEvent[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var action = actions[i];
            uint userId = startUserId + (uint) i;
            action.UserId = userId;
            var e = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            events[i] = e;
            transactionsEvents[userId] = e;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var action = actions[i];
            apiTransactions.ScheduleOrderAction(action);
        }

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(events);

        // now all answers are available, need to apply information
        foreach (var action in actions)
        {
            UpdateActionWithResult(action, transactionsResults[action.UserId]);
            transactionsResults.Remove(action.UserId);
        }
    }
```

`ScheduleOrderAction` adds item to BlockingCollection. Processor executes items from BlockingCollection puts results to transactionsResults and raise corresponding events.

There are a lot of prolems with my implementation:

- I access (and modify) Dictionaries from different threads. For example when one thread remove item from `transactionResults` another thread (Processor) may add item to it.
- I do not want to switch to ConcurentDictionaries because even Dictionary is already too expensive for me (in terms of speed)

Comment: How do you know (Concurrent)Dictionary is too slow? What are the performance requirements? Do you have tested it?

Comment: @SimonMourier perfomance requirements is do not use locks when you can avoid it and every microseconds is important. and also do not use Dictionary when array can be used.

Comment: Well, that's not a performance requirement, that's a wish. You should have numbers, quantities, volumes instead of wishes. Depending on your real needs, using concurrent dictionaries can be enough, especially since it looks you don't seem to master the basics of thread synchronisation (no offense).

Comment: @SimonMourier i've just substituted regular dicionaries with arrays and won about 5 microseconds. why using ConcurentDictionaries when i do not need nor Dictionary neither Concurrent? i think kind of circular array need to be used, probably i will write it myself.

Comment: @javapowered **FIVE MICROSECONDS**? You waste more time calling a delegate once instead a "normal" (or virtual) call. Does it **really** matter?

Comment: @Adriano 5 microseconds doesn't matter, but 50 IS matter. saving 10 times by 5 microseconds IS matter. in future I want to port my system to one that can "do everything" (tick to trade) in 10-50 microseconds. i will buy network card which cost 1000$ and saves 10 more microseconds, i want to have special linux built and so on and so on. right now i'm optimizing the slowest part. it's to early to change a hardware. i'm optimizing c# and rewriting it to c++ (in nearest future).

Comment: @Adriano btw how much time delegate call, normal call, and virtual call spents? I hope that at least normal and virtual calls takes much less than 5 microseconds

Comment: @javapowered take a look to [this test](http://byterot.blogspot.it/2012/05/performance-comparison-of-code.html). Actually I think (of course it's just my personal opinion) that you're _running too fast_. Before you have to take care of this **nano** optimization there are **tons** of other things (for example: you care about few clock cycles and then you use a `foreach`?). I would first write a readable, maintainable algorithm then I would profile to check if I **really** need some optimization and where. Moreover don't forget that **a powerful CPU is cheaper than few hours of development**.

Comment: @Adriano yes i measure how much time do i spent and it's totally (for everything) several hundreads microsecods. Yes I already have a couple of the newest CPUs. i didn't know that foreach is slower than for.